# Is there any idiom that means "delicious"?

Tags: idiom-request

I'm writing a letter and I've already used the word "delicious" in my writing, I'm just looking for a phrase or idiom that completes my sentence, in my mother tongue we have a phrase that says : "your food was as much delicious as its taste is still under my tongue" do we have an English phrase or idiom that I can use in the given concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any idioms, but these are are common and natural phrases:

"Your food left me wanting more."

"Your food was so good I can still taste it."

Answer (score 3):

From what comes to mind, I'd suggest [*finger-licking good*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/finger-licking+good) and [*lip-smacking*.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lip-smacking)

Comment: The fried chicken ad is just about the only place one sees this finger-licking good. It is not much used. Neither is lip-smacking **good**. They are not common and pretty southern.

Answer (score 2):

Your food was really delicious. It hit the spot. It was yummy.

hit the spot could be said here, as in: was satisfying.

yummy or really tasty or a real treat.

And I'm sure there are tons of others as well.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few synonyms that could be used instead of delicious such as [sublime](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sublime) or [divine](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/divine).